How do we format sentences?
Looking at our first questions I've seen Italian sentences in English questions variously formatted:
come questa
"oppure come questa"

o addirittura come questa

e pure in questo modo
Should we set a standard?

The main focus should be on clarity, so whatever makes the post clear is fine in my opinion.
I wouldn't enforce a standard and I'd leave as much freedom as possible to the author, as it's also in their interest to achieve the maximum clarity possible.

That being said, I'll go ahead and encourage the use of 

quotation, for long sentences or whenever the sentence needs to draw more attention

and italic text for inline short sentences, like this one.
I also like using bold or (bold italic) for single terms/expressions, like the verb to use, which is the english translation for the italian verb usare.
I'm neither a fan, nor particularly against the use of "quotation marks for inline sentences".
Finally I would generally avoid the use of preformatted text for inline sentences, as I don't feel like monospace fonts should be used for natural language words.

The point is that it's horrible to see question and answer use different formats :(

I agree, but setting a standard is not the way to go. There would be no feasible way for enforcing it. If the format is terrible you can still edit (or propose an edit) to the post.

Using code and monospace for non-code is actively discouraged in our network.
